# What to do if distinct() command is removing unique project IDs that it shouldn't

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning

I tried to run a distinct() command on my dataset to get rid of duplicated respondents, but when I do that it also gets rid of unique project IDs that I need. It is ok for there to be duplicated IDs for the projects, but RESPNO should not be duplicated.

I have a merged dataset with different aid projects that I have merged with survey data. I use  the following line of code to merge the two data sets

```
Full_dataset <- merge(AidData, OpinionData, by = "Recipient")
```

which produces far too many observations and I notice the respondent IDs from the survey data are duplicated. I also use

Here is an example dataset of what the data frame looks like after the merge. It includes 250 Unique IDs and 46860 RESPNO IDs. I use distinct() within the dplyr package to filter down to the unique RESPNO IDs.

```
set.seed(42)

# Number of rows
n_rows <- 386378

Full_dataset <- data.frame(
  "ID" = rep(1:250, length.out = n_rows, each = ceiling(n_rows/250)),
  "RESPNO" = rep(1:46860, length.out = n_rows),
  "Recipient" = sample(c("Angola", "Benin", "Peru", "UK", "South Africa", "Congo", "Mali", "India", "Greece"), n_rows, replace = TRUE),
  "Mitigation" = runif(n_rows, 0, 100),
  "Adaptation" = runif(n_rows, 0, 100),
  "Fossil_Fuel" = runif(n_rows, 0, 100)
)

Full_dataset <- Full_dataset %>% distinct(RESPNO, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I use the following code in the dplyr package to see that I have 250 unique IDs

```
result <- Full_dataset %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(count))
result
```

Yet when I use the distinct command on the full dataset, I drop down to just 31 project IDs even though I know I should have 250. I don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it.

```
Full_dataset <- Full_dataset %>% distinct(RESPNO, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

How can I use the distinct command to get rid of duplicated respondents (RESPNO) while keeping the correct amount of unique project IDs?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible data set?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Forrest! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (I think you have a reasonable start, but please be explicit about non-base packages like [tag:dplyr]); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! reproducible code is now in the edited question

Comment: I think fixing your merge is the better way to go

Comment: Are the `ID`s unique to each `RESPNO` or do you have repeating `ID`s????

Comment: I have repeating projects IDs since there are only 250 unique projects IDs but there are 46860 unique RESPNOs (respondents)

Comment: Imagine a simpler case where you have one ID with 100 projects and another ID with 1 project. Then you filter to only show one line of each ID. It's no wonder then that you don't see all 101 projects. With many data sets, what your are asking seems unrealistic, so I'm not sure what the desired output should look like.

Comment: You could alternately look for the shortest list of IDs (some may need to repeat) that gets you all the projects, or the set of IDs that (dupes allowed) gets you the most distinct projects, but I don't see how you can take a many-to-many relationship and then expect to extract it into a 1-to-1 relationship.